# How to solve this inequality $2^x -3^{x/2} -1 < 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

First, I came up with an idea that the inequality can be written as $2^x-1 <3^{x/2}$. Taking the square root on both sides, we obtain $(2^x-1)^2 < 3^x$, let it be  $(*)$. In this case, $(*)$ can be solvable iff $2^x-1 = 3$; that is, $x=2$. Substituting to above inequality, we obtained $x>2$, while the graph showed that the solution is $x<2$. So anyone can help, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The derivative has only one root (approx -1.61) so $f$ is $\searrow$ then $\nearrow$, but limits in $\pm\infty$ are easy to figure out, so there is only 1 root to $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Note about the wording:  You squared both sides, rather than taking the square root of each side.

Comment: NOTE: $-3<0$ does not imply that $(-3)^2<0^2$